# Is there any way to PIVOT a SQL Table using indexes so it works for similar tables?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pivot

I'm new to using SQL.

If I have multiple data sets in SQL that I want to pivot the same exact rows/columns with, is there a way to set this up so that it works for all of them. Or, do I still have to put the name of the Column and Row that I want to pivot.

For instance, if I have two separate tables, one that has apples and the other has oranges. The tables show how many of each fruit there are on a certain day. If I want to pivot the table to that it  adds up the total amount of apples on one table and the total amount of oranges on the others, can I use just one function in SQL/Python that would do the same for both tables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- along with an explanation of your performance considerations.  "Pivot" usually refers to a single table, so your question is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: The title says one thing, the question something different. All SQL queries use the indexes defined on the tables they touch, if appropriate. A database has tables not data sets.

Comment: I was thinking about two tables that have similar sets of data and using only one function to PIVOT both of them.

Answer (score 3):

A typical method to do this uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select date, sum(isapple), sum(isorange)
from ((select date, 1 as isapple, 0 as isorange
       from apples
      ) union all
      (select date, 0, 1
       from oranges
      )
     ) ao
group by date
order by date;
```